# Map one dictionary to another using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

Is there an elegant way to map one `Dictionary` to another using Linq in the .NET framework?

This can be accomplished via enumerating with `foreach`:

```
var d1 = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "One", "1" },
    { "Two", "2" }
};

// map dictionary 1 to dictionary 2 without LINQ
var d2 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach(var kvp in d1) {
    d2.Add(kvp.Value, int.Parse(kvp.Value));
}
```

...but I'm looking for some way to accomplish with LINQ:

```
// DOES NOT WORK
Dictionary<string, int> d2 =
    d1.Select(kvp => {
        return new KeyValuePair<string, int>(kvp.Key, int.Parse(kvp.Value));
    })
```

Comment: `yourDictionary.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)` ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use [`ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.8) extension method from [`System.Linq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=netframework-4.8) namespace

```cs
var d2 = d1.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => int.Parse(kvp.Value));
```

Since [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) class implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>` and `ToDictionary` is extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` the code above works fine

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
var d1 = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "One", "1" },
    { "Two", "2" }
};

// map dictionary 1 to dictionary 2 with LINQ
var d2 = d1.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Value, kvp => int.Parse(kvp.Value));
```